# Why gpg-agent not running after Windows 10 restart?

Tags: windows, ssh, putty, gpg4win, gpg-agent

I have configured Putty to run with Yubikey for SSH connections following procedure [here](https://occamy.chemistry.jhu.edu/references/pubsoft/YubikeySSH/index.php). I have configured remote server to accept only key connection. Everything was working as expected.

After Windows 10 restart, set-up was broken. Symptom: Connection error on remote server (Putty not using the correct authentication method). Cause: gpg-agent not running

I solved the issue by running `C:\>gpg-connect-agent KILLAGENT /bye` with result:

```
gpg-connect-agent: no running gpg-agent - starting 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Gpg4win\\..\\GnuPG\\bin\\gpg-agent.exe'
gpg-connect-agent: waiting for the agent to come up ... (5s)
gpg-connect-agent: connection to the agent established
OK closing connection
```

Putty was then choosing the correct authentication method and reading the Yubikey.

**Why did this happen?** Will I need to run KILLLAGENT after every windows restart? or am I missing some other configuration?

Edit:

I have done other system restarts since then and similar issues occurred. Launching Kleopatra before Putty enables the use of the key with Putty as well as running KILLAGENT.

**How to ensure pgp-agent loads correctly at startup?**

Comment: I can't explain the gpg-agent issue, but I don't think it's worth spending much time on this approach to begin with – my opinion is that using GPG for this purpose is *unnecessarily* complex. The same Yubikey that supports PGP card mode also supports PIV (CCID) card mode that Windows understands natively and PuTTY-CAC could use without any additional daemons or agents (and OpenSSH on various platforms is not too far either).

Comment: @user1686 for the moment, I know how to create GPG key pairs and set-up and perform the end-to-end authentification process. It is not yet the case for PIV framework.

Comment: Check this tutorial : [Sign in to Linux from Windows via Yubikey](https://horugame.com/sign-in-to-linux-from-windows-via-yubikey/).